# print preview in wpf with telerik document in rich text box

Tags: wpf, print-preview

telerik rich text box doesnot support print preview,so im trying to implement print preview but im getting the follwing error

Cannot implicitly convert type 'Telerik.Windows.Documents.Model.RadDocument' to 'System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument'

So how can i convert this or how can i achieve this one......

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/silverlight/richtextbox/printing-a-raddocument-without-assigning-to-a-radrichtextbox.aspx) is a good example from the official website.

For further help, I think you should post this question in the [teleric forums](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums.aspx) itself.